Unexpected 401 error at testing RestController
`
I'm trying to test the login method by adding a user, and when I want to login, I get a 401 response insted of 200
UserController
/**
 * Login form
 * @param user the user we are trying to log in with
 * @return JWT
 */
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestBody User user){
    System.out.println(user);
    return userService.login(user);
}


@Test
@DisplayName("Should Login Successful")
public void shouldLoginSuccessful() throws Exception {               
    User user = new User( VALID_USERNAME_EXAMPLE, VALID_PASSWORD_INPUT_EXAMPLE ); 
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> userService.register(user));
    assertFalse(userRepository.findAll().isEmpty()); // Verify the list is not empty
    assertEquals(1, userRepository.findAll().size()); // Verify there is just one user


    String userJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .post("/login")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(userJson)) // Attach the JSON payload
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}`

I tried to acces the endpoint "/login" and I should get a 200 response, but I get a 401 UNAUTHORIZED response

Can you show me more details about userService’s login function?
Also if you use spring security, check SpringSecurity config.
//ex
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()  
        .anyRequest().authenticated();   
}


sorry but how where I could add the code?

If you are using Spring Security in your project, you can add SecurityConfig according to your Spring Boot version anywhere in your project. If you are using version 3.X.X, the following link may be helpful: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33357#issuecomment-1327301183.
Add Configuration annotation in your configuration class. Additionally, remember to include EnableWebSecurity annotation.
